# how to install only package.json dependencies with their own versions by using npm install or yarn

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg, parceljs

I work on a new project, but I can't install packages correctly. I used `npm install`, `yarn`, `npm install --only=dev`, but there aren't enough. I also try like that deleting node_modules and package-lock.json. The state was the same.

We use in the project babel's 6.x version. Babel has a update, 7.x, I think I get the error because of version differences when I run `npm install`, `npm install --only=dev`, `yarn`.

> npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1: �  Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update!
>   npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
>   npm WARN babel-loader@8.0.4 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN babel-loader@8.0.4 requires a peer of webpack@>=2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

I use WebStorm. Before that, I tried to get package for another project with npm install. "Npm" is not successful. WebStorm advice me using Yarn, and I used Yarn. It was worked.

What should I do in the state?

After `npm install`, when I run `parcel index.html`, I get the console error

> "Uncaught TypeError: window.fooes is not a constructor", Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined.

I know that the code doesn't have a problem, because project work on the team's computer correctly.

Comment: Try running `npm i  webpack` after installing the modules

Comment: You can delete ``.lock`` files and try installing again. You should also check ``package.json`` and how version numbers are mentioned in it.

Answer (score 0):

**The first and most important:**

Never use `npm` and `yarn` at the same time. Choose one of them and use that only because they are both using lock files based on the installed packages.

**Which one to use:**

`npm` and `yarn` are both using the NPM software registry database. So in the end the final result when installing packages are the same, but `yarn` does the job much-much faster. `Yarn` was developed by Facebook because the slowness of `npm`. So I prefer `yarn`, I'm not using `npm` commands anymore.

**To your problem:**

- Delete the `package-lock.json` and `yarn.lock` lock files in your project root directory.
- Also delete the whole `node_modules` directory.
- Now you have only your `package.json` file. **Make a backup** of this file!
- Open the original `package.json` and I suggest you to first delete all entries from it
  related to `Babel` and save it.
- Now run the `yarn` command (without params) in the project root (where your `package.json` file is). This should install all your packages again.

Then install the latest packages of `Babel` using these commands:

- `yarn add -D @babel/core`
- `yarn add -D @babel/preset-env`
- `yarn add -D babel-loader`

You may need other packages from `Babel`. Have a look on your backed up `package.json` and search for the latest versions in the [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/) or [Babel's plugins documentation page](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/plugins#docsNav) for the remaining plugins (if any).

Comment: Thank you. It worked almost. When I install packages of Babel by using command, I see "webpack dependency" so  I again install webpack. Webpack get a info **info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.**

I can't solve this. My windows is x64. I can't understand. 
If I ignore fsevents error, when I try `parcel index.html` I got the same error  **Uncaught TypeError: window.fooes is not a constructor**

Comment: @yellowpisagor You can safely ignore the `fsevents` warning. I'm on Windows too and I see this warning a lot. It's totally OK, becuase `fsevents` is needed only on Mac OS. Also the warning says it's `optional dependency`. Watching for filesystem changes will just work four you on Windows, no problem. I don't use `parcel` but I think your `window.fooes` error is because of some bug in your `parcel` config file or in some of your own `.js` file.